# MarkLogic - SPARQL from Java

Tags: java, sparql, marklogic

I'd like to run a SPARQL query using the MarkLogic Java API documented at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java . I've seen examples for running such queries from the console, via the REST API, or via XQuery. But I don't see how to do this using the Java API - is this possible to do?

Comment: Is the edited question still off-topic?  Andy's answer is correct -- there's no direct support for SPARQL in the Java API because there are existing clients like Jena that support querying any triple store, including MarkLogic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a toolkit (e.g. http://jena.apache.org/).

Being a W3C standard, any client library should be able to work with any server.  The level of compliance to the standards is rally quite high.

Documentation:
http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/app_api.html

(Disclosure: I contribute to Apache Jena).